# Where to Find Database Publishing Wizard for SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

As title says I have Database publishing wizard for 2000 and 2005, and now just looking for SQL Server 2008 compatible publishing wizard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool was moved into Visual Studio:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2007/10/15/sql-database-publishing-wizard-is-now-in-visual-studio-orcas.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907585.aspx